# How to call an external API in magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2. I need help in the following query.

How to call an external API on page load or on click of a button in Magento 2.2?

Do we need to create an observer for the same or is there a better way to do it. Will appreciate if any links are provided for step by step process.

Comment: will ajax work for you? I mean if you click on the button and an ajax request will fire for the API call

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to know how to call a basic API. Here is example about GET:

```
$externalAPI = 'https://your/external/api_url'

$ch = curl_init($externalAPI);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 
var_dump($result);
```

From the Magento side, we can use `\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl` class:

```
$apiUrl = '';
$this->curl->addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$this->curl->get($apiUrl);
$body = $this->curl->getBody();
$httpCode = $this->curl->getStatus();
//Quick decoding body
$dataResponse = \Zend_Json::decode($body);
```

> How to call an external API on page load or on click of a button in
> Magento 2.2?
>
> Do we need to create an observer for the same or is there
> a better way to do it.

It depends on the requirements. When do you need to connect to API? Or just display it on the frontend?

Once you know when(or where?) you need to call the external API. You can choose the Plugin, Observer, or Ajax solution.